# jQuery and HTML5 Drag and Drop into Table (Scheduler)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've been using jsfiddle.net to try and prototype a scheduler where the items to be scheduled are dragged and dropped into it. I've gotten dragging and dropping from an "unassigned" list and onto the schedule table working. I've also gotten the ability to remove from the schedule table working. What I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around is moving an item in the table to another part of the table.

The fiddle is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VYWKq/14/). I'd appreciate any suggestions on getting internal drag and drop to work. I've been working on this all day and I'm starting to get blurry vision. Oh, and by all means if you think what I'm doing can be done better, please make the change, just let me know what version the fiddle is up to.

**UPDATE**

As per @SMathew and @darksky I've rebuilt the whole fiddle where I'm not directly shifting the table cells around, but instead their content.

I know you guys recommended using `div`s and/or `span`s, but I want to use the structure of the table, especially the `rowspan` to designate the height of the cell in 30 minute increments. It does work a lot better now, with the only bug being moving cells (or moreso their contents) around because I have to restore cells affected by the `rowspan` at the source site and remove the cells that will conflict with the `rowspan` at the target site.

The updated fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BQqfd/7/).

**UPDATE 2 (FINAL)**

So, I went back to the drawing board again, and after 64 fiddles, I finally got it to do what I want. In the end, the trick to get everything to work fine without manipulating the structure of the table. All I had to do was set cells that are in the way of a rowspan to `display: hidden`.

Anyway, for anyone whose interested, the new fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtypZ/64/). I did discover that Chrome has some issues handling the API. I've noted them in the fiddle (along with a partial rant).

Comment: I would review this article http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: @darksky, yes, I've read that article. I will point out that it was published some 3 years ago. The spec probably didn't change since, but I'm betting that browser support has probably stabalized and become more robust. The API isn't that difficult to work with to be honest and at the end of the day the article does me no good in figuring out how to accomplish what I want. In fact, I'm betting that what I'm missing in functionality is more regular JavaScript logic than Drag and Drop API logic.

Comment: okay. I would personally do this like what Google Calendar is doing: moving divs in front of the calendar table to display events instead of manipulating the table itself like you are doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to make the td elements draggable. When you remove/insert td elements from a table like that, you have to create a bunch of empty cells to balance it out. I would suggest keep the table intact and wrap draggable elements in a div or span tag. This way the table structure never changes. Your code will also be much simpler and efficient.

Comment: +1 I agree. You can even skip the drag and drop headache and achieve this purely by mouse events.

Comment: @darksky I did try to do something with the DnD api and both firefox & safari were just pissing me off. Especially when I wanted to change the visual indication of the object while dragging. Ended up going back to jQuery-ui. I think it still has a long way to go to become usable. It may have gotten better lately. I haven't bothered with it since. Headache indeed!

Comment: I think I see what you guys mean. I've gone back to the drawing board and rewritten the whole thing. The new fiddle is in the update to my question. I'll accept your answer, but I'd still appreciate some help/suggestions on the new fiddle as it's having it's own issues.